# Convert a wav sound to base64 Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: base64, titanium, appcelerator

I'm trying to convert a recorded wav to base64 in order to send the wav with JSON. I get the sound with

var reader = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(recorded_audio_path.path).read();

Reader is now a TiBlob. I want to execute Ti.Utils.base64encode(reader), but reader is a TiBlob and it returns the base64 of "[object TiBlob]". If I make  Ti.Utils.base64encode(reader.toString()), reader.toString() returns the same "[object TiBlob]" in base64, I mean, "W29iamVjdCBUaUJsb2Jd" (base64("[object TiBlob]") = "W29iamVjdCBUaUJsb2Jd")

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this?

http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-3190

i just posted some code for a module to do this conversion, I know a patch is coming from appcelerator, but the module might be useful to you now.

[Clearly Innovative Thoughts - Titanium Appcelerator Quickie: base64encode iOS Module](http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/9546524557/titanium-appcelerator-quickie-base64encode-ios-module)

Comment: I have executed this:   
            var reader = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(recorded_audio_path.path).read();   
            var params = JSON.stringify({  
         binary: Ti.Utils.base64encode(reader),  
            name: 'xxx',
            description: 'yyy'
        });  
And the result of params is {"binary":{},"name":"xxx","description":"yyy"}

Comment: dont quite understand the comment